# Error while bower installing 'bower-angular-translate-loader-static-files.git'

Tags: angular-translate

I am getting the following error while installing "bower-angular-translate-loader-static-files.git" -

```
bower angular-translate-loader-static-files#~2.7.2 cached git://github.com/PascalPrecht/bower-angular-translate-loader-static-files.git#2.7.2
bower angular-translate-loader-static-files#~2.7.2 validate 2.7.2 against git://github.com/PascalPrecht/bower-angular-translate-loader-static-files.git#~2.7.2
bower angular-translate-loader-static-files#~2.7.2 ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/PascalPrecht/bower-angular-translate-loader-static-files.git", exit code of #128 fatal: read error: Connection reset by peer
```

What could be the reason for the same ?

Comment: try "angular-translate-loader-static-files": "~2.7.0"

Comment: same error... the latest version of angular-translate is ~2.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked fine after executing the following command in the command line:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

Apparently there was a problem with proxy or firewall that might cause issues or block ports on git:// urls.